# Setting up custom Authorize roles for MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, authorize

Currently my controller looks like this:

```
public class ProductBrandsController : Controller
```

I've read online that I can apply the `[Authorize]` decorator to each Action, but also to the entire Controller itself.

Is there some way to declare a custom decorator so I would call it like so:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "God")]
public class ProductBrandsController : Controller
```

Or maybe that's too cumborsome. I wouldn't mind creating a new decorator and calling it like so:

```
[Administrator]
public class ProductBrandsController : Controller

//Or 

[ContentManager]
public class ProductBrandsController : Controller
```

Then I would create a custom class to verify if the user that's logged in is in the role.

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you just need to derive from the `ActionFilterAttribute`.

```
 public class AdministratorRequiredAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
 {
      override OnActionExecuting() { }
      override OnActionExecuted() { }
      override OnResultExecuting() { }
      override OnResultExecuted() { }
 }
```

You can override the `OnActionExecuting` method to insert logic to check your user's authentication; when it is not sufficient, you can redirect the user out of the action method with the context object.

Comment: Using your example class name, my decorator would be: `[AdministratorRequired]`? Or what? Might want to fill that in for completion sake. :)

Comment: Correct. The attribute could be used as `[AdministratorRequired]` or `[AdministratorRequiredAttribute]` - the `Attribute` can be left off the attribute name is usage when decorating something.

Comment: It should be something along the lines of `filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(url)`